# Orchard cms page blank when output cache eanble

Tags: orchardcms, outputcache, orchardcms-1.7

When page is loaded first time, it displays as blank page and if we press CTRL+F5, it is loaded. This happens when we enable Output Cache Module. We have login and logout features on the website and we do have cookies setup for 1 month. Due to Output Cache Module, the login and logout links are not changed dynamically as per the user's login/logout status. We use Orchard 1.7. Can anyone give me the solution for this issue?

Comment: Try it on Orchard 1.8, and if still repros, file a bug.

Comment: I have issue on 1.8.1. I did upgrade of orchard from 1.7.2. At 1.7.2 version cache was working. After upgraded it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, Output Cache is used only for non authenticated requests. So, "the login and logout links are not changed dynamically" maybe is not due to output cache module.